# HTC Desire 816 -How to use a particular sim for data usage and restrict the other?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, htc-desire, mobile-data

I have got an HTC Desire 816 phone. I am not able to restrict the data usage to only one sim. If i enable the data usage for the Slot1 sim, the Slot2 sim also gets enabled for data usage. Any idea how to restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

In the dual network manager, you can specify which sim to use for data network connection. 
In Settings > dual network manager > Preferred data network > select either slot 1 or slot 2.